# http.con.httphostconnection exception selenium3 and firefox 49 using gecock driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the code used:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/drivers/geckodriver-v0.9.0-win64/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get(url)
```

Getting below exception.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:42396 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: '3.0.0', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13 10:48:16 -0700'
System info: host: 'sdards', ip: '192.168.1.5', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
    at com.login.CopyOfToolsnew.setupenv(CopyOfToolsnew.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910892/my-code-is-not-working-why/39910945#39910945

Answer (score 0):

Try something:

Use Firefox 49.0.2

Use gecko driver: 
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.11.1

(choose appropriate 32bit or 64 bit version)

You should add these dependecies:

```
<selenium.version>3.0.1</selenium.version>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
  <version>2.52.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", browserWebDriverFilePath);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
D8 = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
D8.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
D8.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: Thank for the help..i am able to launch firefox ..but stuck with another problem